# C++ passing Object by reference in constructor and copy constructor confusion

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference

I very recently started getting into C++, my main language has always been Java.

I want to be able to pass a reference to an object in a constructor so the object constructed can use the passed object and make changes to it.

Doing some research on the subject I've come across copy constructors but I haven't quite understood if they are strictly needed for this operation and what they really accomplish in the first place.

**TLDR: I want to learn how to do the equivalent of the following Java code in C++.**

> Java code

```
class Master {
    private Slave slave;

    Master(Slave slave) {
        this.slave = slave;
    }

    public void doSomethingToSlave() {
        slave.doSomething();
    }

    public void changeSlave(Slave s) {
        this.slave = s;
    }
}
```

> C++ Code ??? -my attempt so far-

```
class Master {
   public:
      Master(Slave& slave);
      void doSomethingToSlave();
      void changeSlave(Slave& s);

   private:
       Slave& slave;  // Is this correct? Do I need to specify that it's a reference?

}

Master::Master(Slave& slave) { // Copy constructor needed?
    this->slave = slave;
}

Master::doSomethingToSlave() {
    slave.doSomething();
}

Master::changeSlave(Slave& s) {
    slave = s;
}
```

> Using Pointers ?

```
class Master {
  public:
      Master(Slave* slave);
      void doSomethingToSlave();
      void changeSlave(Slave* s);

  private:
      Slave* slave;  

}

Master::Master(Slave* slave) { 
    this->slave = slave;
}

Master::doSomethingToSlave() {
    slave.doSomething(); // How do I access the object at slave*? 
}

Master::changeSlave(Slave* s) {
    slave = s;
}
```

Comment: You will not learn C++ by trying to transpose from Java code - the languages are almost completely different. You will need a good C++ text book.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm starting to realize this but for now I'm just working on some small C++ projects in my free time to get to know the language a bit better before I dive into the literature, that's what I did with Java and it made the process of learning about it very enjoyable.

Comment: @Daniel This is not about copy constructors at all. Copy constructors are there for making copies of the same *class* of objects, e.g. `Master(const Master& m) {...}`

Comment: You should use pointers here, instead. Once a reference is initialized it will always refer to the same object.

Comment: @mcrlc I've added a third example using pointers, the problem is that I'm really not sure how I'm able to access the Object at the pointer *slave in the doSomethingToSlave() method.

Comment: @Daniel The code you added is almost correct. Because slave is a pointer, you access the object's methods with the arrow (->) operator: `slave->doSomething();`.
Anyway, I very much agree with @NeilButterworth about the book.

Comment: For class `T`, a default constructor is one that can be called with no parameters (`T()`), a copy constructor is one that takes a reference to `T` to make a duplicate of another instance (`T(cv T&)`, where `cv` is "`const`", "`volatile`", "`const volatile`"/"`volatile const`", or ""), and a move constructor is one that takes an rvalue reference to `T` to steal the contents of another instance (`T(T&&)`).  Any constructor `T(U&)`, where `U` is any other type, isn't a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor (ctor) is used to copy an object, i.e. to create a copy of the object of the same type, given as argument.

In your case,

```
Master::Master(Slave& slave)
```

is not a copy ctor, and a copy ctor is not required for `Master`.

However, `Slave` should have a copy ctor and an assignment operator due to

```
Master::changeSlave(Slave& s) {
    slave = s;
}
```

This is because you are assigning a copy of `s` to the object that `slave` points to. This is likely not what you wanted to do. To reassign the pointer, do use a pointer (rather smart than raw ointer) and not a reference, which cannot be reassigned.

---

Helpful references:

For me, [C++ for Java Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013919424X), especially the summary of differences between C++ and Java, has helped moving from Java to C++.

About cloning: Though assignment operators and regular ctors are usually used, the clone pattern is also helpful in C++. Good examples can be found in Item 25 of [More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X) (Virtualizing ctors and non-member functions).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, what about a clone method inside Slave which returns an indipendent object which is an exact copy of Slave? Is that common practice in C++ or is just a Java thing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which I hope elucidates the behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyType {
    public:
    int value;
};

int main() {
    // value == 1
    MyType obj1{1};
    // initialize a reference to refer to obj1.
    MyType &ref = obj1;

    // value == 2
    MyType obj2{2};

    // ref refers to obj1.
    cout << "A. ref.value = " << ref.value << endl;
    // this actually reassigns the memory in obj1
    // to the memory from obj2.
    ref = obj2;
    cout << "B. obj1.value = " << obj1.value << endl;

    // value == 3
    MyType obj3{3};
    // initialize a pointer to point to obj3.
    MyType *ptr = &obj3;

    // ptr refers to obj3.
    cout << "C. ptr->value = " << ptr->value << endl;
    // now we're just reassigning the pointer value.
    // this is like Java reference assignment.
    // ptr now points to obj2.
    ptr = &obj2;
    cout << "D. obj3.value = " << obj3.value << endl;
    // now we're reassigning the memory at obj2 to
    // the memory from obj1.
    // this is what the C++ reference assignment is doing.
    *ptr = obj2;
    cout << "E. obj2.value = " << obj2.value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
A. ref.value = 1
B. obj1.value = 2
C. ptr->value = 3
D. obj3.value = 3
E. obj2.value = 2
```

A Java reference is actually like a C++ pointer, but Java doesn't let you do the dereference and assignment `*ptr = value`.

However, I agree with what others are saying that approaching C++ with the coding style of Java isn't really a good idea. Modern C++ programs don't really use raw pointers. They use smart pointers or value objects, because C++ doesn't have garbage collection. If you're passing raw pointers around, it's difficult to figure out exactly when a particular object needs to be destroyed.

In your case, I think you'd use a [`std::shared_ptr<Slave>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

A value object is like `Slave slave;`, which is a stack-allocated object if it's declared in a method body, or it's stored directly inside the memory for an object if it's declared as a member of a class or struct.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that did clear some things up.